# How to get feed back message when the input field is empty in Unity Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

i want to get the message if the input field is empty string and

i get this error : Assets/Scripts/FunctionInput_Informasi.cs(37,33): error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

my script is

```
public void simpan_informasiData(){

    var sql = "INSERT INTO t_informasi(judul,keterangan,waktu) VALUES (@judul,@keterangan,datetime());";

    using (var cmd = dbCon.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@judul",field_judul.text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keterangan",field_keterangan.text);


        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(field_judul.text)){
            print="You must fill it...!!!";
        } else 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    }   
}
```

Can you help me...?

Comment: Which line of code are you getting that error on? Double click on the error from the Editor and it will show you which line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move the `if` condition block outside `using` block. This way you will prevent unnecessary memory assignments and you won't be inserting an empty value to your `cmd` command.

Secondly, You cannot assign a value to `print` in unity3D C#. It is a function not a variable. Do something like this

```
public void simpan_informasiData()
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(field_judul.text))
    {
        print("You must fill in then field...!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO t_informasi(judul,keterangan,waktu) VALUES (@judul,@keterangan,datetime());";
        using (var cmd = dbCon.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@judul",field_judul.text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keterangan",field_keterangan.text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```